# How to use grid search for the svm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I think Machine learning is interesting and I am studying the scikit learn documentation for fun. 
Below I have done some data cleaning and the thing is that I want to use grid search to find the best values for the parameters.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


cats = ['sci.space','rec.autos','rec.motorcycles']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( stop_words = "english")


vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)

clf =  SVC(C=0.4,gamma=1,kernel='linear')

clf.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
print(accuracy_score(newsgroups_test.target, pred))
```

The accuracy is: 0.849

I have heard of grid search in order to find the optimal value of parameters but I can't understand how to perform it. Can you please elaborate? This is what I tried but is not correct. I would like to learn the correct way along with some explanation. Thanks

```
Cs = np.array([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10])
gammas = np.array([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1])
model = SVC()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=dict(Cs=alphas,gamma=gammas))
grid.fit(newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target)
print(grid)
# summarize the results of the grid search
print(grid.best_score_)
print(grid.best_estimator_.alpha)
```

## **EDIT** based on the answer received:

```
parameters = {'C': [1, 10], 
          'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 1]}
model = SVC()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters)
grid.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)
print(grid)
# summarize the results of the grid search
print(grid.best_score_)
print(grid.best_estimator_)
```

it returns:

```
GridSearchCV(cv='warn', error_score='raise-deprecating',
       estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
       fit_params=None, iid='warn', n_jobs=None,
       param_grid={'C': [1, 10], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 1]},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0)
0.8532212885154061
SVC(C=10, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=1, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

I need clarifications on these:

```
1)What actually is displayed on the results?
2)Does it also take ranges for C as 1 to 10 or either 1 or 10? 
3)Can you suggest anything    to improve accuracy further?  
4)I noticed that the Tfidf made the accuracy worse even though it 
              cleaned the data from words that dont have any value
```

Comment: You've almost got it, but the `param_grid` takes a dict where the keys are the parameters as str, and the values are lists. So `{'C':np.array([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]), 'gamma':...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass a dictionary of parameters where the keys are the name of the parameter as defined by the model's documentation (1). The values should be a list of the values you would like to try.

The grid search will then call every possible combination of those parameters. There are some good examples with the documentation (2).

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html
2. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

For your script, you also want to make sure that you are feeding the grid search the correct training data, in this case, 'vectors' not 'newsgroups_test.data'.

See below:

```
parameters = {'C': [1, 10], 
          'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 1]}
model = SVC()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters)
grid.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)
print(grid)
# summarize the results of the grid search
print(grid.best_score_)
print(grid.best_estimator_)
```

Please accept the answer if it works. Good luck!

Comment: I have added some clarifications in the question as an edit that have to do with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Improving Accuracy :

---

So, as this is a text classification problem, first of all we should have a look at the text itself and see if it needs any preprocessing. Data Cleaning is very important with tfidf as it does not take context of words into account. 
You can try to make the cases same as in making all the words lowercase so that it doesn't treat the same word differently. You can check for stuff like urls and other content that will be useless to a model and remove all that using regular expressions. In the tfidf model, you can play with some variables like max_features, ngram_range, etc to see what range of values are working well for this use case.

You can explore many other models. Usually we use LSTMs, RNNs, etc for solving text problems. You should explore those models using Keras.

Grid Search

---

Grid Search, Randomized Grid Search can be used to try out various parameters.
It essentially returns the best set of hyperparameters that have been obtained from the metric that you were tuning on. It can take ranges as well as just values.
Searching for Parameters is totally random with Grid Search.
A better alternative is HyperOpt where it actually learns something from the parameters that have been obtained in the past. So working with this will give the best set of parameters much faster.

You can go through this link for a better understanding : https://medium.com/vantageai/bringing-back-the-time-spent-on-hyperparameter-tuning-with-bayesian-optimisation-2e21a3198afb

Comment: Since the example in the question is entirely reproducible can you use code to pass your ideas please? For example what do you consider the best preprocessing to achieve optimal accuracy? I have actually used tfidf and the max features and other parameters but only reduced the accuracy for some reason. Examples would be greatly appreciated.Thanks